# How to set up project-level permissions for SVN?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, svn

I have an SVN server running on Ubuntu 9.04. Inside /var/svn, there are various projects - /var/svn/foo, /var/svn/bar, etc. I want to be able to give user "A" full SVN permissions for 'foo', but not 'bar', and vice versa - user "B" could have permissions to 'bar' but not necessarily 'foo'.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html):

> In the case of Apache, one needs to
>   load the mod_authz_svn module and then
>   add the AuthzSVNAccessFile directive
>   (within the httpd.conf file) pointing
>   to your own rules file. If
>   you're using svnserve, you need to
>   make the authz-db variable (within
>   svnserve.conf) point to your rules
>   file.

The file svnserve.conf is inside each repo directory, while AuthzSVNAccessFile

> specifies a file containing the
>   permissions policy for paths within
>   your repositories

(always from he documentation)

Comment: This is pretty much the exact configuration setup I'm using to give instructors read rights and students read/write on their own repos, and prevent students reading other repos. You can address specific repositories with a colon.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you do not allow your users direct file-level manipulation on your repository via svn command line tool or by svnserver. set up apache and use http[s] to access the repository - in such setup you can get granular access control. give read/write access to your repository just to user under which apache runs [www-data] and deny it to anyone else [ including local users ].

read [here](http://davidwinter.me.uk/articles/2006/03/03/access-control-for-subversion-with-apache2-and-authz/) or [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch06s04.html).